# morphia datastore fetch, save, delete query

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

How to convert below code to List

```
DBCursor users = morphia.datastore().createQuery(User.class).fetch().getCursor();
```

Also can you give some sample code for delete and save. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `asList()` instead of `fetch()`

Comment: Feel free if you'd like @Tiw.  But those are all documented already: https://morphia.dev/.  But the question is just one tiny step above "write the code for me" as it is.

Comment: Then probably it's better vote to close it than to answer it. Anyway I was reviewing LQPs, and fyi I OKed it.